# Google App Engine Blobstore upload File and get Path

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob, blobstore

I was successfully tested Blobstore upload [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview). But it use serve method to view the file. I can't find any way to get file path. Normally in php when we upload a file we get the file path, so we can embed that file in html. How can I do that in BlobStore. I searched on stackoverflow and google, I could find python examples but I can't find any for java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the tutorial example:

```
res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString());
```

you have to create a link in your HTML page that looks like:

```
<a> href="/serve?blob_key=.... blob_key_of_this_blob ....>Serving the BLOB</a>
```

Comment: How can I attach uploaded image? I tried to do the following, but wasn't successful. <img src='/serve?blob_key=<%= request.getParameter("id") %>'></img>

Comment: Does <%= request.getParameter("id") %> contain the blob_key you want to serve? You have to get the blob_key of your image from the blobstore

Comment: There is another trick. You can have served the images by Google instead of doing it youself. It is faster and cheaper. See this article (you don not need GWT): http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/